# Is it possible to hatch a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

With [Ditto](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ditto/) being released into the wild, Niantic's comments are

> Ditto has been known to disguise itself as other Pokémon, so keep an eye out, some Pokémon may actually be Ditto, and when you capture them, there’s a chance that Ditto will reveal itself. If you do encounter a Pokémon that is Ditto in disguise, the Pokémon in that specific encounter will also reveal itself as Ditto for other Trainers.

While Niantic only mentioned Ditto being disgused in the wild as other Pokémon, it is possible to hatch a Ditto?

Comment: I don't think there have been any reports of hatching a Ditto yet, but I'll keep my eyes peeled!

Comment: I don't think it'll be possible either. (Lore wise) But I might wery well be wrong!

Comment: @Vemonus Ditto on keeping my eyes out

Comment: @Karlyr That is what i had thought, seeing how Ditto is one of the unbreedable Pokemon. But we shall see what Niantic has in store

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found two sites that both say that Ditto is not hatchable.

- [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ditto_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Side_game_data) (under Side Game Data)
- [Pokèmon Go Wiki](https://pkmngowiki.com/wiki/Ditto_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

Considering the lore and that Ditto disguises itself as lower tier Pokémon, it makes sense that it isn't hatchable since it should be fairly easy to find.  Niantic is likely (but not necessarily) following the lore of the game when it comes to Ditto and how it breeds. The Bulbapedia describes Ditto in its own egg group. It states:

> As Pokémon in the Ditto group cannot breed with members of its own group, Ditto cannot be hatched from an Egg.

If this is true and the game was designed to follow this, then you shouldn't be able to hatch a Ditto from an egg.

**Update:**  The [IGN Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Ditto) states that you **cannot** hatch a Ditto from an egg under the "Additional Ditto Catching Techniques."

Comment: Another player I met on the street said that he had hatched two so far; now that I think about it, there is zero credibility to his comments. I should have asked what egg it hatched from at least, but did not.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is. I hatched one myself last week and only took notice because my friend was so surprised. (Can't remember which, 2/5/10) I didn't take any scshots but I'm sure these accounts will start to crop up soon, so take my word for it or don't!

Comment: Check your journal, it will display Pokemon that are hatched

Answer (score -3):

I hatched a Pidgy, which turned into a Ditto, I was surprised to hatch the Pidgy, to be honest.

Answer (score -3):

Can confirm that Ditto hatched from a 2 km egg for my partner today and this completed her quest entry too. Tried trading her mine and that didn't trigger.

Comment: This answer goes against a lot of well-established sources. It'd also be easy to prove- post a screenshot of her journal and it'll show that a ditto hatched from an egg. Unfortunately, without this proof, I'm going to have to downvote.